# Why did the FDA approve Biafine only in 2006?

Tags: sun-burn, united-states

Biafine is a topical non-steroidal medication, which has been used use in France for over 25 years. Why did the U.S. Food and Drug Administration approve Biafine for prescription only in 2006?

Comment: I do not understand. According to [FDA K964240](https://www.accessdata.fda.gov/scripts/cdrh/cfdocs/cfpmn/pmn.cfm?ID=K964240) it was approved 1997?